# Images aren't showing up on Moodle mobile

Tags: javascript, html, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I created html e-learning using Animate CC, and I had problems when I trying it out in the Moodle app. On the content page, all bitmap images are not displayed at all, only text is displayed.

here's the code I use,

```
(elearning_c.bmp_area = function() {
    this.initialize(img.bmp_area);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Bitmap();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(0,0,50,50);




// bmp_area
    this.instance = new elearning_c.bmp_area();
    this.instance.parent = this;
    this.instance.setTransform(-60,888.9,15.557,71.338,-90);




elearning_c.properties = {
  id: 'DC13DBC2CDF2A8419AB311DD38BFD644',
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  fps: 24,
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  opacity: 1.00,
  manifest: [
    {src:"assets/M02K00H01/bmp_area.png?1594349632559", id:"bmp_area"}
  ],
  preloads: []
};
```

Can anyone suggest me on how to solve this issue?

[This is how it looks in the moodle app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EcAR.jpg)

[This is how it should look, it's using the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRXgF.jpg)

Comment: Hi, it will be very helpful if you add what code you have tried already, so people can give specific solution/suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I've added the code that I used, hopefully it can be clearer

Comment: I don't know if this is still valid but you might need to publish it correctly and use App Packager
https://community.adobe.com/t5/captivate/best-way-of-getting-edge-animate-animation-into-moodle-course/td-p/5438655